# In Sphinx, how do I hide the section numbers when producing a LaTeX PDF?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, toctree

The [documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html) says that "Numbering up to a specific depth is also possible, by giving the depth as a numeric argument to `numbered`," which is a `toctree` option. But giving it a depth of 0 or 1 doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Your problem might be related to this bug: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/591

Comment: Possibly, although I think that only applies to producing HTML, not LaTeX. I remember reading somewhere that, by default, Sphinx produces numbered sections in LaTeX even if the `numbered` option is not given.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the answer from [a similar question on TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80117), applied to `conf.py`, as shown below:

```py
latex_elements = {
'preamble': r'''

\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname #1ignore\expandafter\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\let\sectionignore\@gobbletwo
\let\latex@numberline\numberline
\def\numberline#1{\if\relax#1\relax\else\latex@numberline{#1}\fi}
'''}
```